# /etc/pm/power.d scripts not executing after update to 13.10

Tags: power-management, 13.10, pm-utils

I recently updated to Ubuntu 13.10 and realized that scripts in `/etc/pm/power.d` do not fire anymore. Has something changed in the way pm-utils work? Is there any way to make it work.

I have a script which automatically changes the brightness on my monitor if the power cable is plugged out and I would like to be able to use it again.

**UPDATE**
I realized that the main reason why the scripts aren't executing automatically is because the `upowerd` is not running. If i run `upower --monitor`, the scripts start to execute whenever I connect or disconnect the charger.

The `man upowerd` says the following:

> upowerd provides the org.freedesktop.UPower service on the system message bus. Users or administrators should never need to start this daemon as it will be automatically started by dbus-daemon(1) whenever an application calls into the org.freedesktop.UPower service.

Why doesn't the upowerd start automatically on boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding the

```
upower -e
```

line to my `/etc/rc.local` file, which just enumerates the available power sources and starts `upowerd` if it's not already running.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by just installing pm-utils, afterwards the scripts ran properly:

```
sudo apt-get install pm-utils
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've already had the pm-utils installed...